# Filtering string from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, filter, substring, streamreader

I'm working on a application that filters a line of text and puts the filtered text into a file.

Example of non filtered line:

```
0&
1&
2&
3&&&&&
4&&
5&
9&&&&&&&131015&&&&H&HEA100&1712&&1001&2&S235JR&&&HEA100 - 1712&&&&&&&S&&0.96&&&&2&&&1.7&0.2&0.2N&1001.nc
```

What I want to do is filter `H&*code*&*code1*&&*code2*&code3*&code*&&&` from that line of text.

But before that I have to filter the `0&1&` till the `H&` part of the line.

The code I've come up with(comments are in dutch sorry):

```
string[] delete = new string[] { "0&", "1&", "2&", "3&&&&&", "4&&", "5&", "9&&&&&&&" };

//Geeft het pad op.
string path = @"C:\test.txt";

//Maakt een tijdelijk bestand aan
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

//Leest het bestand in vanuit het opgegeven pad
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))

//Schrijft de string naar een tijdelijk bestand
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
{
    string line;
    //Checkt iedere nieuwe regel naar een van de arrays die verwijderd moeten worden
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line != delete[0])
            if (line != delete[1])
                if (line != delete[2])
                    if (line != delete[3])
                        if (line != delete[4])
                            if (line != delete[5])
                                if (line.Substring(0, 8) != delete[6])
                                {
                                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    string durp = line.Substring(9);
                                    sw.WriteLine(durp);
                                }
                                if (line.StartsWith("H&") == true)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(line.Substring(2, 6));
                                }
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

    int index = text.IndexOf('&');
    string orderNr = text.Substring(0, index);
    if (index > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(orderNr);
    }

}

File.Delete(path);
File.Move(tempFile, path);
```

The problem is that I need to run the application twice because the first time I run the application it just prints 0& on my screen. When I run it a second time the 131015 gets printed on my screen like it's supposed to.

I need to extract the number between the `9&&&&&&&` en the other `&` character. After that all the `&` characters need to be replaced by a `;` character.

Comment: This is what we call it as [Arrow code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern) ;)

Comment: Sooo...what should your output look like?!

Comment: Arrow code? I'm fairly unexperienced in programming so I don't know what that means. I know the delete string is awful programming but with my skill I couldn't fix it into a loop.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't use Regex?

Comment: I don't know Regex, since I'm very new to programming.

Comment: So I can convert a & into a ; character with regular expressions?

Comment: @OmgItsK   you can replace as such  YourString.replace("&",";")